# Any GUI filechooser that works with Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy, photo, filechooser

New to coding but I tried to use the tkinter file dialog module in my kivy app but it does not work together. Is there any other filechooser that would work? I know kivy has their own but it is not ascetically good looking. Basically what I want is to prompt the devices native file browser to pop up and import an image into my kivy app.